# How many integers between 1 and 10,000 are neither squares nor cubes?

Tags: combinatorics, perfect-powers

Question in proofs class. No idea how to figure this one out. I've been giving all questions an honest effort - this seems unorthodox.

Please help get me started

Comment: Count the squares and cubes less than $10,000$?

Comment: And how would one go about doing that in under a week?

Comment: You think it would take a week to count how many squares are less than $100^2$?

Comment: Now, counting the **cubes** less than $10,000$ is a much tougher proposition. It would help a lot if I knew what the cube root of $10,000$ was, but I don't. Somewhere between $20$ and $30$ I guess?

Comment: 21 (rounded off)

Comment: All right, then, there are $21$ cubes between $1$ and $10,000$ (inclusive); they are $1^3,2^3,3^3,4^3,5^3,6^3,7^3,8^3,9^3,10^3,\dots,19^3,20^3,21^3$.

Comment: So there are $100$ squares and $21$ cubes, and $100+21=121$. But the problem is a bit trickier than that because of double counting. Some numbers are **both** squares **and** cubes, such as $1=1^2=1^3$ and $64=8^2=4^3$ and $729=27^2=9^3$ . . .

Comment: With a simple script the counting takes virtually no time.

Answer (score 6):

Squares: $1^2,2^2,...,100^2 \Rightarrow$ we have 100 squares.

Cubes: $1^3,2^3,..., \lfloor \sqrt[3] {10000} \rfloor^3=21^3=9261 \Rightarrow$ we have 21 cubes.

Numbers that are squares and cubes: $1^6,2^6,..., \lfloor \sqrt[6] {10000} \rfloor^6=4^6=4096 \Rightarrow$ we have 4 numbers that are squares and cubes.

By inclusion-exclusion principle, follow that we have $10000-100-21+4=9883$ number which are neither squares nor cubes.

Comment: observe that we don't need to consider the powers >6.